# How to install jupyter- failed building wheel for pywinpty

Tags: python, installation, pip, jupyter

I've been trying to install jupyter for the past 2 hours and I keep getting this error:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pywinpty
Failed to build pywinpty
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pywinpty, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried installing pywinpty by itself (pip intstall pywinpty in cmd) and it gives the same wheels error.

I used this guide from jupyter to attempt installation: https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/notebook-classic.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If that doesn't work, Try this as Admin in cmd

```
pip uninstall pip
```

and then,

```
python -m ensurepip
```